# Getting user facebook likes and attributes in Android(Facebook SDK 3.18)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.0

This is my login function:-

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }
```

This my function to get facebook likes and attributes:

```
public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                    id=profile.getString("id");
                    // getting name of the user
                    name = profile.getString("name");
                    // getting email of the user
                    email = profile.getString("email");
                    //about=profile.getString(about);
                    bio=profile.getString(bio);
                    birthday=profile.getString(birthday);
                    gender=profile.getString(gender);
                    link=profile.getString(link);
                    locale=profile.getString(locale);
                    political=profile.getString(political);
                    quotes=profile.getString(quotes);
                    relationship_status=profile.getString(relationship_status);
                    relegion=profile.getString(relegion);
                    website=profile.getString(website);

                    Log.d("Name",name);



                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
        //Getting Facebook Like
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
             new Request(
                     session,
                     "/{id}/likes",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.d("Facebook Likes", response.toString());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
        /*Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // response should have the likes
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Facebook Likes", response.toString());
            }
        };
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/likes", null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();*/
```

ERROR:-
**D/Request﹕ Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.**

I am getting other attributes as 
28959-29486/com.example.sensetest D/Profile﹕ {"id":"************","email":"***********","first_name":"***","gender":"male","last_name":"****","link":"****","locale":"en_US","middle_name":"Singh","name":"Rituraj Singh Rathore","timezone":5.5,"updated_time":"2015-03-22T11:01:08+0000","verified":true}

The problem is I am not able to get facebook likes of user who has logged in. I have tried also [How to get user likes from Facebook with Android sdk 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293233/how-to-get-user-likes-from-facebook-with-android-sdk-3-0).
But I didn't got desired result.
Help me regarding this, Where am i doing wrong. What should i do to make it right?